# Google tasks API

Tags: android, calendar

I would like to be able to add reminder tasks to the google calendar.  I'm just writing a simple test app, and it's able to query calendars and events using CalendarContract.

I'm NOT talking about a reminder in an event to send notifications when the event is near.  What I'm talking about is related to google tasks.  On my online google calendar, I have what looks like an additional calendar titled 'Reminders'  When I right-click on it, I have an option to change it to Tasks.  These are the entries I would like to create/update with my app, but I can't find any examples of the right way to do it.

I started looking at the Google Tasks API, but I expect that requires and internet connection to be successful.  I would like to update the local copy and allow it to sync with the calendar, the same way events can be created without an internet connection using CalendarContract.  I know it's possible since my google calendar app has an option to add a reminder.  Any direction on how to tackle this would be appreciated. Searching for this has been difficult since reminder and task both have alternate meanings in this context.